# I am trying to make the GET method to show all files in webserver directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, webserver

Hello I am trying to add a GET function where it would be able to display all files in the directory my webserver is allocated on

I removed the GET function completely, and thought it would just default the method by displaying all files in directory, but the server sent me a error saying that it doesn't support the method GET

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

from io import BytesIO


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #def do_GET(self):
     #   self.send_response(200)
      #  self.end_headers()
       # self.wfile.write(b"Page is only for POST")

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b"POST")
        import json
        list_output = json.loads(body.decode("utf-8"))
        newdata = open(str(list_output[0]) + ".json", "w")
        newdata.write(body.decode("utf-8"))
        response.write(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())
        print(body.decode("utf-8"))

httpd = HTTPServer(('192.168.1.107', 8079), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

the error I get is

```
192.168.1.107 - - [02/Dec/2020 19:48:47] code 501, message Unsupported method ('GET')
```

In reality I expected this to appear in the webpage

[image: Directory page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

For now it can display the requested file. But thats enough for me!

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json
from io import BytesIO
import os
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        with open(str(self.path)[1:], 'rb') as file: 
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(file.read())
            print(self.path)

    def do_POST(self):  
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b"POST")
        list_output = json.loads(body.decode("utf-8"))
        newdata = open(str(list_output[0]) + ".json", "w")
        newdata.write(body.decode("utf-8"))
        response.write(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())
        print(body.decode("utf-8"))

httpd = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8079), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```